# Is it possible use @Service/@Component instead of @Controller annotation SpringMVС?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Is it possible use @Service/@Component instead of @Controller annotation in Spring MVC
( I checked this out and it doesn't work) but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Controller` annotation is a specific type that, like all spring annotations, is derived from the `@Component` annotation. Note that, depending on use case, it may work, and it may not. Controller classes are often used for mapping server requests to responses.

You can view [this Geeks for Geeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-controller-annotation-with-example/) for more info on when to use the `@Controller` annotation. If you have `@RequestMapping` annotations in your class, you will not get the same behavior with a Component as you will with Controller.